# UTC time in python with datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

How can I use `datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.date.today()` together? In case I am running code A it throws error and Code B other one. I want to use both of these in my code.

**A**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

path = datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')
for year in range(2014, 2018):
    for month in range(start_month_number, 13):
        this_month = datetime.date.today().replace(year=year, month=month, day=1)
        print(this_month)

error - AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

**B**

```
import datetime
path = datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')
for year in range(2014, 2018):
    for month in range(start_month_number, 13):
        this_month = datetime.date.today().replace(year=year, month=month, day=1)
        print(this_month)

 error- AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'utcnow'
```

Code B run fine in case there is no line -->curryear = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y')

Comment: A: why don't you use `datetime.today().date()` instead? Also, please clarify: what is `curryear` used for? what value has `start_month_number`? B: check your imports, here you import a module `datetime` vs. a class `datetime.datetime` in A.

Comment: and finally: if you wish your dates to refer to UTC, use `datetime.utcnow()` consistently, i.e. replace `datetime.today()`.

Comment: actually I can taking path in this format... path = datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')..if using import datetime in this case throw an error.

Comment: ok, it's just a bit confusion if there are variables that are not actually part of the question/problem/error ;-)

Comment: my bad. updated the question.

Comment: coming back to your question: what are you actually trying to achieve? I mean, you could simply write `this_month = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=1)` - no need for `replace` or anything related to UTC.

Comment: how can i solve this ...
import datetime
path = datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')
Exception: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'utcnow'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either import the module that you need, **or** the classes you need from the module - not both. Then, write your code according to what you have imported:

**A:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date

path = datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')
for year in range(2014, 2018):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        this_month = date(year=year, month=month, day=1)
        print(this_month)
```

**or B:**

```
import datetime

path = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(f'{category}/%Y%m%d/%H:%M')
for year in range(2014, 2018):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        this_month = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=1)
        print(this_month)
```